# How to turn on/off airplane mode in IOS 5.1 using private API

Tags: iphone, ios, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to toggle on/off airplane mode in IOS 5.1 using private frameworks.

In AppSupport.framework, `RadiosPreferences` has a property to get/set the airplane mode and set the value

**./AppSupport.framework/RadiosPreferences.h**:

```
@property BOOL airplaneMode;
```

**./AppSupport.framework/RadiosPreferences.h**:

```
- (void)setAirplaneMode:(BOOL)arg1;
```

How can I use these methods? Do I need to use `dlsym` somehow to create an object and call the methods? Can someone help me with sample code or ways to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [jrtc27 describes in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13393520/119114) (and [I mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481535/119114)), you need to grant your app a special entitlement in order to *successfully* change the `airplaneMode` property.

Here's a sample entitlements.xml file to add to your project:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.SystemConfiguration.SCDynamicStore-write-access</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.SystemConfiguration.SCPreferences-write-access</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.radios.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**com.apple.radios.plist** is the file where the airplane mode preference is actually stored, so that's what you need write access to.

**No**, you don't need to use `dlopen` or `dlsym` to access this API.  You can add the **AppSupport** framework to your project directly (with the exception that `AppSupport.framework` is stored on your Mac under the `PrivateFrameworks` folder). Then, just instantiate a `RadiosPreferences` object, and use it normally.  The entitlement is the important part.

For your code, first [use class-dump](http://stevenygard.com/projects/class-dump/), or [class-dump-z](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=class-dump-z), to generate the RadiosPreferences.h file, and add it to your project. Then:

```
#import "RadiosPreferences.h"
```

and do

```
RadiosPreferences* preferences = [[RadiosPreferences alloc] init];
preferences.airplaneMode = YES;  // or NO
[preferences synchronize];
[preferences release];           // obviously, if you're not using ARC
```

I've only tested this for a jailbroken app.  I'm not sure if it's possible to acquire this entitlement if the device isn't jailbroken (see Victor Ronin's comment).  But, if this is a jailbreak app, make sure you remember to sign your executable **with** the entitlements file.  I normally sign jailbreak apps with [ldid](http://code.google.com/p/networkpx/downloads/detail?name=ldid), so if my entitlements file is **entitlements.xml**, then after building in Xcode [**without** code signing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12548876/119114), I would execute

```bsh
ldid -Sentitlements.xml $BUILD_DIR/MyAppName.app/MyAppName
```

[Here's Saurik's page on code signing, and entitlements](http://www.saurik.com/id/8)

Comment: I can confirm that it works on iOS 6.1. Also, ensure that the embedded entitlements xml uses UNIX line terminations otherwise the kernel won't run the app.

Comment: @Zmaster Do you also confirm this won't work on a non-jailed broken phone?

Comment: @Lolo If you're talking about using this on an AppStore app then it's definitely not possible. You need to both include AppSupport (a private Framework) and add the entitlement (also reserved): if you do any of these your app will be refused.

Comment: No, I am actually just thinking about getting this to work on my personal phone, i.e. uploading it from xcode onto my iphone. I have given up on hoping to become rich by selling apps through the app store but am not ready yet to jail broke my brand new iphone just to see if I can get this to work.

Comment: @Lolo, sorry for the delay in responding. No, you can't do this without a jailbroken device.

Answer (score 3):

Add `com.apple.SystemConfiguration.SCPreferences-write-access` to your entitlements plist and set it to true (you may need to create the plist). I believe the following should work - if it doesn't I can look later tonight when I'm able to test it:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework"];
BOOL success = [bundle load];

Class RadiosPreferences = NSClassFromString(@"RadiosPreferences");
id radioPreferences = [[RadiosPreferences alloc] init];
[radiosPreferences setAirplaneMode:YES]; // Turns airplane mode on
```

Comment: "com.apple.SystemConfiguration.SCPreferences-write-access" entitlement is beyond private API. It's only available on jailbroken devices.