# Bypassing code sign with xcode 4.5 for iOS6

Tags: xcode, ios6

We used to modify the SDKSetting.plist to allow the build of unsigned apps, by setting `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED` to `NO`.

But since xcode 4.5, this file seems encrypted (here is its path : `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist`).

Does somebody know how to build unsigned apps for iOS6?

Comment: It's not encrypted.  Maybe you were looking at a binary version of the file?  In which case you could open it with the Mac **Property List Editor** application.  Anyway, also note that you originally had an error in your path (which I fixed in an edit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```sh
sudo cp /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist ~/Downloads

sudo chmod 777 ~/Downloads/SDKSettings.plist
```

- open ~/Downloads/SDKSettings.plist
- Edit in the popup window of XCode

```sh
sudo mv ~/Downloads/SDKSettings.plist /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

- restart xcode

Comment: apps still crash upon launching for me after performing the edits on 10.8.2 with xcode 4.5.1. Is there anything else that needs to be done besides the Info.plist and SDKSettings.plist edits?

Answer (score 1):

First quit Xcode,

Then in terminal execute

```
sudo vim /Applications/Xcode.app/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/SDKSettings.plist
```

Navigate using arrow keys (or `k` and `j`) then press `i` to edit. Make your changes, then press escape followed by `:wq`

Start Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I managed to edit the file from another XCode on another computer.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing `SDKSettings.plist` you can also just pass `xcodebuild` an argument of `CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO`.