# Xcode 4.5 Fake Code Signing

Tags: xcode, code-signing

I've just upgraded my system from OS 10.7 to 10.8 running Xcode 4.5 and the documentation [from this source](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Developing_without_Provisioning_Profile) regarding fake code signing doesn't appear to mention a modifiable iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec file for a Xcode 4.5 installation.

Prior to upgrading my system to OS 10.8 I was running Xcode 4.3.2 on OS 10.7 and I had fake code signing working like a charm. Since the upgrade my apps are crashing like AppSync is not installed. I checked the logs and it is indeed a code signing issue.

Has anyone had any luck with Xcode 4.5 and fake code signing?

I was in the process of developing an app for the iPhone and now things have seem to hit a brick wall *sigh*. Any info on the subject would be appreciated as I'd like to avoid downgrading if I can help it.

Comment: Why don't you just use legitimate code signing?

Comment: Because jailbreaking is [legal, ethical, and fun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_jailbreaking#Legal_status).

Comment: Why to write "why don't just use legitimate code signing" if question is directly about jailbreaking and not about morals/laws/philosophy? Really important question, I have the same issue: on XCode 4.5 old way to bypass code signing doesn't work, something new is required.

Comment: It looks like here there are decision how to disable code signing in XCode at all: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456112/bypassing-code-sign-with-xcode-4-5-for-ios6 After that it is possible to sign your code yourself from command line and/or use ldid.

Comment: @VASoftOnline did that method of bypassing code signing in the link work for you?

Comment: Yes, I was able to disable code signing requirement in XCode, so it builds unsigned, and then sign them with ldid. However, there are some underwater stones, but they are also can be solved, watch here for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768109/how-to-use-ldid

Comment: @VaSoftOnline, thanks for providing that link, I got my app running on my device now :)  If you answer the question with the link provided I will give you the credit for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to build application & run it on iOS device without joining any development programs on jailbroken phone:

1. Disable code signing requirement in xCode. Read here how to do that: [Bypassing code sign with xcode 4.5 for iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456112/bypassing-code-sign-with-xcode-4-5-for-ios6)
2. Build application without signature and sign it manually with ldid utility. Some additional instructions are available here: [How to use ldid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12768109/how-to-use-ldid)

Comment: How to build project to .app if I haven't got an Apple Developer account ?