# CommandLine Option in Xcode 4.5.2 (Mountain Lion)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, code-signing, jailbreak

I am trying to debug iPhone apps on my jailbroken phone, and everything has gone well besides the step I am following [here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Xcode#Replacing_codesign_with_ldid):

```
7. Open iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec.
For Xcode 4.3 the file is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec
For Xcode 4.2 the file is at: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec
For older versions the file is at: /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Plug-ins/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/Resources/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec
```

I am having trouble finding the file (iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec). I am using Xcode 4.5.2, on Mountain Lion. I can find the directory at:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/iPhoneOS Build System Support.xcplugin/Contents/
```

but I cannot find the Resource directory which is said to contain the Resources/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec file. Where can this be found?

If they moved it, then my next question will be where is the `CommandLine = "/usr/bin/codesign"` stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your file is in the directory.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Specifications/iPhoneCodeSign.xcspec
```

Answer (score 1):

That guide is not suitable for iOS6 and XCode 4.5 since that file has been removed. In order to fake code signing on iOS6 refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12884327/846273).