# Support Multiple SDK on iOS Development and Debugging on Device

Tags: ios, ios6, ipod-touch, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I'm new to ios development and I've some questions about sdk. I'm not paid developer yet, I sign up for free. Then, I download and install xcode 4.6 with iOS 6.1 sdk. I developed some basic app for understanding development process.

If I'm not a paid developer, I cannot debug apps on device, is it true?

I have ipod touch 4th gen with ios 5.1.1, How can I debug app on this device ? I tried different things but I didn't.

I changed architectures setting in app, I remove app requirement,I change target sdk, and I set the device using for development. But I didn't solve the problem. When I build and run app, I get this error:

> The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired
>   certificate/private key pair in your keychains

I have no provisioning profile. I want to add profile but I get this error:

> Too few items in teams.

How can I solve these problems and debug apps on my iPod ?

Comment: If you don't want to jailbreak or buy a license, you may try the steps mentioned in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456112/bypassing-code-sign-with-xcode-4-5-for-ios6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short answer: You are right.

You can not build app to your device if you don't own an iDP. Once you enroll a paid iDP, you can generate certifications and provisioning files step by step with Apple's documentation. If you really want to debug on a device, you can jail break it and install a sync patch, which will skip the signture verify and run your code without iDP. But when you want to submit it to AppStore, of course you need a paid account.

Comment: Thanks for attention, I will pay, but how can I debug app on iPod ? I have iOS 5.1.1 on iPod but xcode has iOS 6.1. It is possible to debug without any change in project settings?

Comment: You should change the deployment target to 5.1 or lower for debug in your 5.1.1 iPod. Select Project File in Project Navigator Panel, select your target in "TARGETS", you can find the "Deployment Target" in the Summary tab.