# Code Sign Error with Xcode4.6 on JailBroken Device

Tags: iphone, ios6, jailbreak, xcode4.6

I have jail broken device and would like to build the app on the jail broken device. I followed the following links to build the application

[Bypassing code sign with xcode 4.5 for iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456112/bypassing-code-sign-with-xcode-4-5-for-ios6)

[How can I deploy an iPhone application from Xcode to a real iPhone device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246422/how-can-i-deploy-an-iphone-application-from-xcode-to-a-real-iphone-device)

[Test iOS app on device without apple developer program or jailbreak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952820/test-ios-app-on-device-without-apple-developer-program-or-jailbreak)

Created the self signed certificate.

Modified the file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist

Modified CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO, ENTITLEMENTS_REQUIRED to NO in SDKSetting.plist file.

After that tried to build the application for the device I got the following error

**Code Sign error: A valid provisioning profile matching the application's Identifier could not be found**

What things I need to do to build an app on Xcode4.6 jail broken device?

I am building the app on MAC OS 10.8.2 using XCode 4.6 on iOS 6.1sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used 4.6﻿ and I didn't have any trouble at all with this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0JS0D2tXGY

Comment: I am able to build now.Did not select Don't Code Sign Option.